# Permission denied to execute cfx command from Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, linux-mint

Recently I have downloaded the latest version of Firefox Add-on SDK, 1.13.2 in my Linuxmint 14 KDE. It worked fined so far as shown in the below commands:

```
ikrz@iklg570 /media/MyDrive/Dev/MozillaAddons/sdk $ source bin/activate
Welcome to the Add-on SDK. Run 'cfx docs' for assistance.
(sdk)ikrz@iklg570 /media/MyDrive/Dev/MozillaAddons/sdk $ cfx docs
bash: /media/MyDrive/Dev/MozillaAddons/sdk/bin/cfx: Permission denied
(sdk)ikrz@iklg570 /media/MyDrive/Dev/MozillaAddons/sdk $
```

But, as you can see in above output in terminal (Konsole) the permission to run cfx command was denied. This was working fine when I was using Linuxmint 14 MATE, but 1.12 of Add-on SDK.

I am having one more trouble which is related to user permission questioned at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/554849/automount-ntfs-partitions-in-linuxmint-14-kde).

Comment: what does ls -la say for the bin directory of the SDK?

Comment: @canuckistani
`ikrz@iklg570 /media/MyDrive/Dev/MozillaAddons/sdk/bin $ ls -la`
`total 30`
`drwx------ 1 ikrz ikrz 4096 Feb 12 12:43 .`
`drwx------ 1 ikrz ikrz 4096 Feb 12 12:43 ..`
`-rw------- 1 ikrz ikrz 2368 Feb 12 12:43 activate`
`-rw------- 1 ikrz ikrz 4420 Feb 12 12:43 activate.bat`
`-rw------- 1 ikrz ikrz 2677 Feb 12 12:43 activate.ps1`
`-rw------- 1 ikrz ikrz 1132 Feb 12 12:43 cfx`
`-rw------- 1 ikrz ikrz  256 Feb 12 12:43 cfx.bat`
`-rw------- 1 ikrz ikrz  550 Feb 12 12:43 deactivate.bat`
`drwx------ 1 ikrz ikrz    0 Feb 12 12:43 integration-scripts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files in the bin directory do not have the execute bit permission:

https://gist.github.com/canuckistani/5008348

As a test I downloaded 1.13.2 as a tarball and unpacked it, you can see what the directory should look like in the 'correct.sh' part of the gist. I used the following commands:

```
wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/labs/jetpack/addon-sdk-1.13.2.tar.gz
tar xfz addon-sdk-1.13.2.tar.gz
```

The directory I did this in is owned by my user, and is a local file system. YMMV.

Comment: thank you so much for your support. Now I understand why there is no enough permission. I am using NTFS drive to store my files. This drive's mount point have not set to full persmission. I should try to resolve it first. Thanks again. :)

Comment: After resolving with regard to permissions for NTFS drive, it is now working. Thank you. :)